# QuickReturnListView computescrollY position faster

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm adapting the [QuickReturnListView](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView) from LarsWerkman to my application but it takes too long to scroll the list. My application shows rows with thumnails but all are the same size.

```
public void computeScrollY() {
    mHeight = 0;
    mItemCount = getAdapter().getCount();   
    mItemOffsetY.clear();

    for (int i=0;i<mItemCount;++i)
    {
        View view = getAdapter().getView(i, null, this);
        view.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            mItemOffsetY.add(i,  mHeight);
            mHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    scrollIsComputed = true;
 }
```

One thing I've thought to make this compute faster is not to called for every item to the getView because all my rows has the same size, but if I use the same view.getMeasuredHeight() for all the items the effect of the QuickReturnListView gets faulty. Can someone help me to improve this calculation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your code works like this, and your bottom line all the same size, you can make faster execution using this code:

```
public void computeScrollY() {
    mHeight = 0;
    mItemCount = getAdapter().getCount();   
    mItemOffsetY.clear();

    if(mItemCount>0) {
        View view = getAdapter().getView(0, null, this);
        view.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        for(int i=0; i<mItemCount;i++) {
            mItemOffsetY.add(i,  mHeight);
            mHeight += h;
        }
    }
    scrollIsComputed = true;
 }
```

you should know that the element at the box mItemOffset 0 is always 0 with your code?

You should also know that with this code you will know the height of all elements (even those not shown) without taking into account the number of columns?

Moreover, it is not very clean call getView manually recreate all the instances needed to make the View all this only to calculate the height.

I hope to help you

Comment: Thank you, I already tried that and I thought it wasn't working but in the end it was that I wasn't taking into the account the fact that the header of the list has a diferrent height!!

Comment: Are you using a arraylist ? This code is different then the library. Can you share? I have  if (mItemOffsetY == null || mItemOffsetY.length != mItemCount)
  {
   mItemOffsetY = new int[getAdapter().getCount()];
  }

Comment: may the gods be with you